# Why will my program only compile up to 16 records?

Tags: c++, arrays, oop, file-io, time

Below is my program, it is supposed to create an object array, then tells. how long each loop takes to run. The loops are just reading/writing from file and memory and the program is supposed to compare the methods when it is finished. For some reason the program will only display the times if the number of records created is 16 or less. I can't seem to spot why. Also I can't see why my ratio's aren't working. Possibly since each variable is less than a second so it's trying to divide 0 by 0 maybe?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <ctime>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

class TestRecord
{
private:
int _number;
string _data;
public:
TestRecord ()
{_number = 0; _data = "no data";}

TestRecord (int number, string data)
{_number = number; _data = data;}

void setNumber (int number)
{_number = number;}

void setData (string data)
{_data = data;}

int getNumber() const
{return _number;}

string getData() const
{return _data;}

friend ostream &operator <<(ostream &out, TestRecord &records)
{
    out << records._number << " " << records._data;
    return out;
}
};

int main ()
{
    string string256 = "AaronAaronAaronAaronAaronAaronAaronAaronAaronAaronAaronAaronAaronAaronAaronAaronAaronAaronAaronAaronAaronAaronAaronAaronAaronAaronAaronAaronAaronAaronAaronAaronAaronAaronAaronAaronAaronAaronAaronAaronAaronAaronAaronAaronAaronAaronAaronAaronAaronAaronAaronA";
int recordsToBeCreated = 0;

cout << " How many records should be created?" << endl;
cin >> recordsToBeCreated;

TestRecord* recordObj = new TestRecord[recordsToBeCreated]; 

//--------------------------------------writing

clock_t startTime1 = clock();
for (int count = 0; count < recordsToBeCreated; count++)  //fill object array
{
    srand(count);
    recordObj[count].setData(string256);
    recordObj[count].setNumber(rand()% 10000 + 1000);

}
clock_t endTime1 = clock();
ofstream outFile;

clock_t startTime2 = clock();
for (int count1 = 0; count1 < recordsToBeCreated; count1++) //write to disk
{
    outFile.open("data.txt");
    outFile << recordObj[count1] << endl;
}
clock_t endTime2 = clock();
outFile.close();
//----------------------------------------reading
clock_t startTime3 = clock();
for(int count2 = 0; count2 < recordsToBeCreated; count2++) //read/write from mem
{
    int *tempNumber = new int;
    string *tempString = new string;

    *tempNumber = recordObj[count2].getNumber();
    *tempString = recordObj[count2].getData();

    delete tempNumber;
    delete tempString;
}
clock_t endTime3 = clock();
ifstream inFile;
clock_t startTime4 = clock();
for(int count3 = 0; count3 < recordsToBeCreated; count3++) //read/write from disk
{
    int *tempNumber = new int;
    string *tempString = new string;
    inFile.open("data.txt");

    inFile >> *tempNumber;
    inFile >> *tempString;

    delete tempNumber;
    delete tempString;
}
clock_t endTime4 = clock();
inFile.close();
//---------------------------------random reading comp

int randomNumber = rand()%recordsToBeCreated;

clock_t startTime5 = clock(); //traverse array to random index
for(int count4 = 0; count4 > randomNumber; count4++)
{
    recordObj[count4];
}
clock_t endTime5 = clock();

clock_t startTime6 = clock();
inFile.open("data.txt");
for(int count5 = 0; count5 < randomNumber; count5++)
{
    string *tempString = new string;
    cin.ignore();
    inFile >> *tempString;
}
clock_t endTime6 = clock();
inFile.close();

double seconds1 = endTime1 - startTime1;
seconds1 = seconds1 / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
double seconds2 = endTime2 - startTime2;
seconds2 = seconds2 / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
double seconds3 = endTime3 - startTime3;
seconds3 = seconds3 / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
double seconds4 = endTime4 - startTime4;
seconds4 = seconds4 / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
double seconds5 = endTime5 - startTime5;
seconds5 = seconds5 / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
double seconds6 = endTime6 - startTime6;
seconds6 = seconds6 / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;

cout << "Time to write to memory:                      " << fixed << setprecision (5) << seconds1 << " seconds" << endl;
cout << "Time to write to file:                        " << setprecision (5) << seconds2 << " seconds" <<  endl;
cout << "Ratio of (write to disk)/(write to memory):   " << seconds2/seconds1 <<  endl;
cout << "\n\n";
cout << "Runtime to read from memory:                  " << setprecision (5) << seconds3 << " seconds" <<  endl;
cout << "Runtime to read from disk:                    " << setprecision (5) << seconds4 << " seconds" <<  endl;
cout << "Ratio of (read from disk)/(read from memory): " << seconds4/seconds3 << endl;
cout << "\n\n";
cout << "Runtime to find random index from memory:     " << setprecision (5) << seconds5 << " seconds" <<  endl;
cout << "Runtime to find random line from disk:        " << setprecision (5) << seconds6 << " seconds" <<  endl;
cout << "Ratio of (read from disk)/(read from memory): " << seconds6/seconds5 << endl;



delete [] recordObj;
system("pause");
return 0;
```

}

Comment: More info please. What happens with the number is greater than 16? Does it crash? Print an error?

Comment: Oh my. Please get rid of all these pointers and manual allocations. They are totally unnecessary and make the code way more complex and error-prone.

Comment: @KonradRudolph: This is obviously a beginner. Would you have him/her skip the fundamentals and rely on libraries for everything?  It's good to point out alternatives, but I wouldn't jump on this person for learning how things actually work.

Comment: Code looks good to my eye.  Appears to run alright on ideone: http://ideone.com/J2Lw7  Only problem I can think of is if it fails to write the file (as it does on ideone)

Comment: The dynamic allocation is required by my assignment. The program is pretty much finished, it's just with numbers greater than 16, nothing at all happens. 16 or less and it prints the time that it takes to process everything. I'm using Visual C++ 2010 if that helps any.

Comment: It opens `outFile` file for writing many times, closes once. So strange.

Comment: @sircrisp: And that's the right way to learn.  I wouldn't want to work with anyone who hasn't had to debug memory corruption, allocation errors, etc. Once you understand all that you will move on to use standard classes like `std::vector`, but for now, stick with doing things manually.

Answer (score 2):

EDIT:

This line

```
for(int count4 = 0; count4 > randomNumber; count4++)
```

is dangerous. You're not getting into the infinite loop only because the `count4` wraps around `2^32-1` sooner or later, but this is a bad condition. Shouldn't it be `count 4 < randomNumber` ?

EDIT2:

The allocation of tempInt/tempString can be done only once (before the loop), not in the loop itself.

Old stuff:

First (rather obvious) suggestion: stop allocating everything dynamically.

Instead of

```
for(int count2 = 0; count2 < recordsToBeCreated; count2++) //read/write from mem
{
   int *tempNumber = new int;
   string *tempString = new string;

   *tempNumber = recordObj[count2].getNumber();
   *tempString = recordObj[count2].getData();

   delete tempNumber;
   delete tempString;
}
```

do just

```
for(int count2 = 0; count2 < recordsToBeCreated; count2++) //read/write from mem
{
   int tempNumber;
   string tempString;

   tempNumber = recordObj[count2].getNumber();
   tempString = recordObj[count2].getData();
}
```

As you should know, `tempNumber` and `tempString` would be allocated on stack and they are deallocated at the end of each iteration.

Now the errors.

In this loop

```
for (int count1 = 0; count1 < recordsToBeCreated; count1++)
{
    outFile.open("data.txt");
    outFile << recordObj[count1] << endl;
}
```

you overwrite the file on each iteration. I guess this should be

```
outFile.open("data.txt");
// write 'em all
for (int count1 = 0; count1 < recordsToBeCreated; count1++)
{
    outFile << recordObj[count1] << endl;
}
```

And in this loop

```
for(int count3 = 0; count3 < recordsToBeCreated; count3++) //read/write from disk
{
   int *tempNumber = new int;
   string *tempString = new string;
   inFile.open("data.txt");

   inFile >> *tempNumber;
   inFile >> *tempString;

   delete tempNumber;
   delete tempString;
}
```

once again you are reopening "data.txt" and thus you only read the first line.

This should be (with the allocations removed)

```
inFile.open("data.txt");
for(int count3 = 0; count3 < recordsToBeCreated; count3++) //read/write from disk
{
   int tempNumber;
   string tempString;

   inFile >> tempNumber;
   inFile >> tempString;
}
```

Comment: I fixed the file overwriting but I'm still having the same problem with nothing happening when I enter 17 or more. The allocation is required by the teacher to familiarize ourselves with pointers.